# if statement is not working inside controller mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the controller:

```
int id = 1;
var book = db.books.Where(r => r.bookid == id).First();
string onebook = book.bookid.ToString();
if(onebook != null)
{
    return Content(onebook);
}else
{
    return Content("Noting");
}
```

if there is value id(inside database) it will result and show the value

but if there is invalid value or null I don't get custom error but instead I get the err:

> Sequence contains no elements
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` (not `.First()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`,  It returns default value if the sequence contains no elements.:

```
var book = db.books.Where(r => r.bookid == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even simpler:

```
var book = db.books.FirstOrDefault(r => r.bookid == id);
```

Comment: how to set if statment

Comment: @waliahmad As you did already or even simpler : `return book == null ? Content("Nothing") : Content(onebook);`

Comment: I did but there are some good people whom down voted